# Как задать разный  class span-у на разных страницах?

Tags: html, css, php

Добрый день. не могу сообразить как сделать.
Есть span ( простая ссылка для скрытия открытия фильтра (div, через display скрывается, открывается)), итак на одной странице он (фильтр) открыт, а на другой странице закрыт. Подскажите как реализовать? или куда копать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<span id="test"></span>
<script>
   if(window.location.href=='http://site.com/page.htm')
      document.getElementById('test').setAttribute('class','first');
   else
      document.getElementById('test').setAttribute('class','second');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Через php или javascript - как удобнее...

```
<div class="first_class <?php if (page == 'закрытый фильтр') echo "hide_div_class"; ?>">blah-blah-blah</div>
```

ну а на спан натравить `jquery $("span").toggle();`